# How to get json response of a custom object using wcf REST services?

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

How can I serialize an object to return a custom type?

```
//The response is null. 
http://localhost:50604/GameService/Getbyid?id=1

[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public MyClass GetById(int id)


[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(User))]
public partial class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; } //How will I serialize this?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `UriTemplate` for your operation so your Id is probably never passed in and your method works with default value = 0.

Try this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="Getbyid?id={id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public MyClass GetById(int id)
```

`CreatedByUser` will be serialized automatically if filled and if User is data contract as well.

Comment: I already added a uritemplate but it still doesnt rerialize the return object.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't realize return object"?

Comment: i mean "serialize" sorry for that.. it works fine when i remove this line of code >> public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

Comment: How do you get data? Btw. your `CreatedByUser` is not marked with `DataMember` so it will not be serialized.

Comment: I tried to put the <code>DataMember</code> but still not serializing. I tried to remove the <code>virtual</code> keyword and it works BUT the <code>CreatedByUser</code> is empty.

Comment: And is it filled with data on the service?

Comment: Not.. Because i think it needs to be Virtual for Entity Framework to fill it in..

Comment: So after three days you are telling me that you are using Entity framework? Where is that mentioned in your question? How do you expect to get an useful answer if you are not able to describe your problem with all relevant details? There is a new rule saying that questions and answers should not contain discussion in comments because once they to it usually means that question has low quality and low details to be answered. Use eager loading (`Include`) to load your user and make sure there is no cyclic reference or use `IsReference=true` in your `DataContract`.